# While giving accelerator it is not moving faster as it like

Tags: engine, pressure

I own a second hand Pulsar 220 bike ,while I am giving accelerator more it is not moving fast as well as performance is down.and getting sound form there.
It is engine , clutch plates ,and carburettor problems.

Can you calrify in this.this 2016 model bike .it contains any engine problem or clutch plates issue .

Comment: When did you last gve it a service? spark plug, air filter etc?

Comment: I just purchased yesterday.i does not give any service . actually as well as it is getting sound in carburettor while giving accelerator.should I like to sold this bike .